# Calling C from Rust with external headers in C file

Tags: c, rust, cmake, header

I am trying to call C code from Rust, I succeeded! The only issue I get is when I try to take other libraries with me... the documentation says that you should include all headers in the one file you try to load in Rust, so I do this in the .c file...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "dependencies/glfw-3.3.4/include/GLFW/glfw3.h"

int someFunc() {
    int i = glfwInit();
    glfwTerminate();
    return i;
}
```

But when I run the Rust program, it says glfwInit and glfwTerminate are unresolved symbols... If I do this instead:

```
...

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

...
```

I get the error in my Rust program that there is no such directory, though the library was linked correctly using CMake... I read something about a cmake crate, so I am guessing it has something to do with that, but at the moment I am completely clueless. I must say that I am new to both Rust and C/C++ (student in Computer Science...) :slight_smile:

Note that when I remove any glfw related stuff, everything works correctly!
I am thinking if I can somehow invoke CMake from the build.rs file, that I can link everything in the C project correctly, right? I just do not understand very much CMake since I have been doing everything with an IDE (CLion by jet brains) and very limited commands in CMakeLists.txt.

This is how the project is organised...

project structure:

```
// generated with cargo new rust_project ...
    .../rust_project/      
       c_project/          // This was generated with the IDE for C (CLion)...
          dependecies/
             glfw-3.3.4/
                include/
                ...
          CMakeLists.txt   
          MyCFile.c         
          ...              
       src
          main.rs
       build.rs
       cargo.toml
       ...
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(c_project)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/glfw-3.3.4)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/glfw-3.3.4/include)
##some more libraries... not currently included in MyCFile.c !##

add_library(c_project MyCFile.c)

target_link_libraries(c_project PRIVATE <other_libraries> glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} <other_libraries>)
```

MyCFile.c:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int someFunc() {
    int i = glfwInit();
    glfwTerminate();
    return i;
}
```

main.rs:

```
extern "C" {
    fn someFunc() -> i32;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        println!("{}", someFunc());
    }
}
```

build.rs

```
extern crate cc;

fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .file("c_project/MyCFile.c")
        .compile("library");
    /*
     * I am guessing here goes something along the lines:
     * "CMakeLists.txt".execute (as pseudo code...)
     */
}
```

cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "rust_project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]

[build-dependencies]
cc = "1.0.70"
```

the error message upon "cargo check":

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `version_zero v0.1.0 (D:\...\rust_project)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `D:\...\rust_project\target\debug\build\rust_project-bf398c13c8af8b0c\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-msvc")
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  running: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-Z7" "-Brepro" "-W4" "-FoD:\\...\\rust_project\\target\\debug\\build\\version_zero-54603a96dee57aac\\out\\c_project/MyCFile.o" "-c" "c_project/MyCFile.c"
  MyCFile.c
  c_project/MyCFile.c(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GLFW/glfw3.h': No such file or directory
  exit code: 2

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-Z7" "-Brepro" "-W4" "-FoD:\\...\\rust_project\\target\\debug\\build\\version_zero-54603a96dee57aac\\out\\c_project/MyCFile.o" "-c" "c_project/MyCFile.c" with args "cl.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 2).
```

I used: https://crates.io/crates/cc, https://liufuyang.github.io/2020/02/02/call-c-in-rust.html, https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/interoperability/c-with-rust.html

---

CMake was installed through: https://cmake.org/download/.

Downloaded the option: "Windows x64 Installer: Installer tool has changed. Uninstall CMake 3.4 or lower first!  cmake-3.21.2-windows-x86_64.msi"
Honoustly don't know how you would do it with the zip files...

tried to uninstall the current CMake, and downloaded version 3.4 (and installed it).

Also changed the build.rs file to:

```
use cmake;

fn main() {
    let dst = cmake::build("c_project");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", dst.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=MyCFile");
}
```

cargo check compiles just fine, cargo run, will produce an error:

```
<lots of file paths...>
  = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'MyCFile.lib'
```

Note that I do not get any indications anymore of cmake not being installed...

Comment: Linkage is performed in `CMakeLists.txt` and without viewing it it is impossible to say what you are doing wrong. Please, add [mcve] into the question post.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer since I seem to be unable to edit the post...

Comment: Hm, you should definitely be able to [edit] your post. And you forgot to provide the **exact error message**.

Comment: So your `build.rs` doesn't use CMake at all. Have you checked the docs about that usage? E.g. [that one](https://docs.rs/cmake/0.1.45/cmake/).

Comment: I have tried it! but it gets me this:
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '
  failed to execute command: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
  is `cmake` not installed?
Also when I type in a general cmd prompt something like cmake --help it says the command is not recognised... Tried installing cmake, but seemingly failed, it installed a GUI, but I guess there is an SDK?

Comment: So your initial problem is how to **install** CMake, not about *using* it, isn't it? Installation of CMake GUI should come with CMake itself. How exactly have you tried to install CMake? Please, add this attemp into the question post.

Comment: updated post... I am still thinking, if it would be possible to just build the library through CLion, which produces a .lib file... and then just do "println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=c_project/cmake-build-debug/c_project");" from main in build.rs... I tried it, but this produces LNK2019: unresolved external symbol hello... and LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'. The latter can be solved I presume through building the library as a x64 instead of x86... which I do not know how to do yet.

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot open include file: 'GLFW/glfw3.h': No such file or directory` - the error states that the c compiler cannot find the header file glfw3.h from your build point. The cc crate provides the `.include` for it's builder. Find out where you have the `glfw3.h` file and pass its path into the `include` builder method:

```
fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .file("c_project/MyCFile.c")
        .include("path/to/glfw3.h")
        .compile("library");
    /*
     * I am guessing here goes something along the lines:
     * "CMakeLists.txt".execute (as pseudo code...)
     */
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it failed... I get:
library.lib(library.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glfwInit referenced in function someFunc
          library.lib(library.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glfwTerminate referenced in function someFunc
Note that if I build the C project with CLion, everything is still found properly...

Comment: Link the built lib to your project by adding this to your `build.rs` (after compiling the lib)
`println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=path/to/generated/lib")`

Comment: Tried it, the cc docs state that the variable .compile() is the name of the library, though I am not sure where you are supposed to find the path to which... Still get those linking errors...

Removing the calls of glfwInit and glfwTerminate from the .c file seems to solve the issue, but not really since I do need those functions. I am not quite sure if it is an error concerning declaration or initialisation.

Comment: a correction: the function .compile takes the name of the generated lib as argument.
The lib should be generated somewhere under your target directory, and you shouldn't need to link it manually after compiling with cc in the build.rs. But you can also use the `.out_dir` to set the output location (then you would have to link it).
Anyways, it appears you need to also link the glfw lib to your rust project. find it's and link it with `println!` in the build.rs or pass it in RUSTFLAGS env variable

Comment: Did some more testing, you say "find it's and...", I have to find the glfw.lib file? I did it, still failed... though the other functions still function correctly. Isn't there a way to just precompile the C project and link it without cc or cmake? Making use of #[link(...)].